# Populating a Table from Database in next sheet (using multiple Filters)

Tags: excel, vba, vba6

'i have 2 sheets, 1 with database & other has table which i need to populate with count thats derived by filtering the data. daily the data needs to be populated in the table against the date

post filtering a set of filters for todays date the derived count of lines needs to be populated in sheet 2 which has the criteria date wise. and this report will be run daily so i just need to continue old values and past the same for todays date. if post filtering the count is 0 it should populate 0 against the criteria for that day. so on i want to filter and populate, again filter and populate for all the criteria's (filtering field for each criteria is diff)

**Table for Ref**

Criteria                               04-Oct  05-Oct  06-Oct

COF Prep Stage CAT1/2 – delay > 1 day   13       2       2

COF Prep Stage CAT3 – delay > 1 day      6       7       7

COF Prep Stage CAT4 – delay > 1 day

Current code - filtering only for first criteria but than stuck on how it will go to another sheet populate the filter count in the table against the particular date & criteria'

```
    With Sheets("1.COF WIP>1 1day")

    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    
    With .Range("$A:$Y")

    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="CAT 1-2"

    .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=">1"

    .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=xlFilterToday

End With

End With
```